# Need advice on Sphinx query and index configuration

Tags: sphinx

below are tables I need to index in Sphinx
[image]

News has many projects linked to it via the news_projects table...

My question is it advisable to have all the project names in one text field so that it can be searched on?

This is my query :

```
//query to get the project names and make all project names appear in one field separated by comma.
SELECT
  news.id
  news.headline,
  news.body,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT projects.project_name) as related_projects
FROM  news 
LEFT JOIN news_projects on news.id = news_projects.news_id
LEFT JOIN projects on news_projects.project_id = projects.id
GROUP BY news.id
```

This will then output rows with project_name column formatted as 'name,name2,name3'

Im a bit undecided weather to use this or just make the project_id an attribute.. Having the project_name as text is definitely of big help because it can be searched on...

Please.. I need you opinion on this.. thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this a sphinx or thinking sphinx question? It's tagged as thinking-sphinx but seems to be about straight sphinx?

Comment: Just sphinx.. I removed the thinking sphinx tag already...

Comment: this is unrelated to your question, but you don't need [id] in the news_projects table. You just need PRIMARY(news_id, project_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project name is useful for searching on, then definitely keep it. I would recommend concatenating with a space instead of a comma, though (although it may not matter under the hood for Sphinx when you're using the default settings).

It's probably also useful to have the project ids as a Multi-Value Attribute (MVA) - which means you can limit search results to news items within a specific project. No reason to not have both, really.

Comment: Having integer project ids also performs a lot better, simply because you're not matching on a string.

Comment: Indeed, but it depends what you want to do: limit search results to specific projects (use the MVA for project ids), or have project names included in the text that will be matched against search queries (project names field).

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify related_projects field with [sql_joined_field](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-joined-field). It may be faster because you can remove grouping from the main query.

```
sql_query = SELECT id, headline, body FROM news

sql_joined_field = related_projects from query; \
    SELECT news_projects.news_id, projects.project_name \
    FROM news_projects \
    JOIN projects ON projects.id = news_projects.project_id \
    ORDER BY news_projects.news_id ASC
```

If you make delta indexes, though, you'll have to copy delta conditions to all joined fields (same with ranged queries), which can be somewhat of a pain.